# Skip the "Check if File Already Exists"

Tags: php, forms, image-uploading

I am creating a form to upload photos to a contest. I have no problems in the desktop version, but smartphones have the problem that every photo is loaded as "image.jpeg" or "image.jpg" thus preventing the upload of a next, because it detects an image of the same name. How can I overcome this problem?
This is my code:

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "Il file selezionato non è un'immagine. ";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Spiacente, una foto con lo stesso nome è già stata inviata. ";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size 500kb
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 2000000) {
        echo "Spiacente, le dimesioni della foto superano il limite consentito. ";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Spiacente, i formati consentiti sono jpg e png. ";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Spiacente la tua foto non è stata inviata. ";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
            echo "Messaggio Inviato. La tua foto ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " è stata inviata con successo. ";
        } else {
            echo "Spiacente, si è verificato un errore nel caricamento della tua foto. ";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You could just remove the if condition where it checks if the file already exists? But if you do that, you should randomly generate a file name.

Comment: Give name to every image.

Comment: but if I remove the if when a user upload the photos, overwrites with the previous already loaded, right?

Comment: @NanaPartykar how can I do?

Comment: Append `time()` to `image name`.

Change `$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);` To `$target_file = $target_dir.time().basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists, if it exists, then create a new filename with time attached to it(or something similar), and then move the uploaded file.

a sample is given below, you should modify it to fit your need

```
    $file_name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    if (file_exists($dstFile . $file_name))  {
        $path_parts = pathinfo($dstFile . $file_name);
        $file_name = $path_parts['filename'] . '-' . time() . '.' . $path_parts['extension'];
    }
    $dstFile .= $file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$dstFile)
```

Comment: But I have to leave the current if file exist? and then paste that?

Comment: Do you want to over write the old file? Or you want to keep the old file and create new file name for the new file? The solution I provided is for the second